# How to pass a row object to the backing bean using JSF 2 and RichFaces?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, cdi

I am using RichFaces's ordering list to display a table custom Command objects to the user.  The user uses a form to create new commands which are then added to the list.  Here is the orderingList implementation:

```
app.xhtml

<rich:orderingList id="oList" value="#{commandBean.newBatch}" var="com"
listHeight="300" listWidth="350" converter="commandConverter">

<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="New Batch Details" />
</f:facet>
<rich:column width="180">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Command Type" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{com.commandType}"></h:outputText>
</rich:column>
<rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Parameters" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{com.parameters}"></h:outputText>
</rich:column>
<rich:column>
    <h:commandButton value="Remove #{com.id} : #{com.seqNo}"
        action="#{commandBean.remove(com.id,com.seqNo)}" 
        onclick="alert('id:#{com.id} seqNo:#{com.seqNo}');"/>
</rich:column>
```

My troubles began when I tried to implement a remove button which would send a command's ID and seqNo to the backing bean (cb) to be removed from the list.  Here is the backing bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CommandBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private CommandType type;
private String parameters;

private List<Command> newBatch = new ArrayList<Command>();

private Set<Command> commandSet = new HashSet<Command>();

private String msg = "not removed";

public CommandType[] getCommandTypes() {
    return CommandType.values();
}

public void addCommand(CommandType type, String parameters) {
    newBatch.add(new Command(type, parameters));
}

CommandType getType() {
    return type;
}

void setType(CommandType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

String getParameters() {
    return parameters;
}

void setParameters(String parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
}

public List<Command> getNewBatch() {
    return newBatch;
}

public void setNewBatch(List<Command> newBatch) {
    this.newBatch = newBatch;
}

public Set<Command> getCommandSet() {
    return commandSet;
}

public void setCommandSet(Set<Command> commandSet) {
    this.commandSet = commandSet;
}

String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void remove(Integer id, Integer seqNo) {
    for(Command c : newBatch) {
        if(c.getId() == id && c.getSeqNo() == seqNo) {
            newBatch.remove(c);
            msg = "removed " + c;
            return;
        }
    }
    msg = String.format("%d : %d", id,seqNo);
}
}
```

When the Command (com)'s id and seqNo are passed via `#{cb.remove(com.id,com.seqNo)}` they are both 0.  I also read somewhere that null values are transformed to 0's, so that would explain it.  I also tried to pass the Command object directly via `#{cb.remove(com)}` but the Command was null when bean tried to process it.

I'm betting there is something off with the scoping, but I am too new to JSF to figure it out...

***UPDATE***

I have eliminated the conflicting @Named tag and have updated the html to reflect the new name of the bean, namely commandBean.  Still having issues though.

Comment: This was a rapid Proof-of-Concept, so it's frankensteined together from a bunch of examples.  Have any links handy to where I can find the *right* way to do it?

Comment: Passing arguments to methods via EL is only available from EL-3. You should be sure that's your version of EL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the two values as request parameters:

```
<h:commandButton ... >
    <f:param name="id" value="#{com.id}"/>
    <f:param name="seqNo" value="#{com.seqNo}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

and get retrieve them in managed bean like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
System.out.println(request.getParameter("id"));
System.out.println(request.getParameter("seqNo"));
```

Comment: Even though it seemed a bit clunky, this worked great!

Comment: @AlexanderAavang you might want to write a wrapper method to get the request object. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a value from a variable that is used in a for-cycle after the cycle is over. The @action is being resolved on the server side, by the time the @var is null.

You can do this:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{commandBean.remove()}" … >
    <a4j:param assignTo="#{commandBean.idToRemove}" value="#{com.id}"/>
</a4j:commandButton>
```

The a4j:param resolves the value on client side, when the button is clicked it sends it to the server.

Comment: Unfortunately doing this didn't work.  For some reason, the remove method was never called.

Comment: @AlexanderAavang you might need to use `a4j:commandButton` with `execute="@this"` to make it work properly.